# Password hashing and verification

Tags: python, python-3.x, hash

I'm trying to learn now about hashing and verification of passwords, I was told to use the module `passlib` and `pbkdf2`. 
The code I was recommended was:

To Hash:

```
 from passlib.hash import pbkdf2_sha256 
 hash = pbkdf2_sha256.hash("password", rounds=20000, salt_size=16)
```

To Authenticate:

```
from passlib.hash import pbkdf2_sha256
pbkdf2_sha256.verify("password", hash)
```

I think I understand all the code here, except for one thing, where would the Hash for any given password be stored, and mainly how to have the input for the password that i want to verify, 
I tried using

```
password = input("Enter a password here: ")
```

That worked since I tried printing the hash, and each time i entered the same password, i got the same hash, so up to that point, everything is working.

now, i tried resetting password, by a new input, and then having the authentication code after it, thinking that I have set password as a new value, I should be able to get a False value each time i entered a password that does not match to the first one entered, yet, there, no matter the second input, returns True

here's the full code

```
from passlib.hash import pbkdf2_sha256

password = input("Enter a password:")
hash = pbkdf2_sha256.hash("password", rounds=20000, salt_size=16)
print(hash)

password = input("please enter your password:")

print(pbkdf2_sha256.verify("password", hash))
```

Then I tried setting the 2nd password as "password2" and that returns false always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are hashing and verifying the text "password" rather than hashing and verifying the input. Minor change to your variable names to make it a bit clearer what you need to change:

```
from passlib.hash import pbkdf2_sha256

password_input = input("Enter a password:")
hash = pbkdf2_sha256.hash(password_input, rounds=20000, salt_size=16)
print(hash)

password_confirm = input("please enter your password:")

print(pbkdf2_sha256.verify(password_confirm, hash))
```

Comment: Oh, didnt catch it, you are right, thanks, its working now